# ¿Como evito que un "paciente" se registre dos veces? PHP MySQL

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Estoy creando un pequeño "sitio" para un amigo medico, que necesita llevar un control de pacientes, el necesita meter los datos por cada cliente como Nombre Completo y Direccion, pero quiero que al registrar un nuevo paciente, verifique si este ya esta registrado,tomando en cuenta Nombre y apellidos.

-Nombre de la BD **"drfreddy"**
-Tabla **"pacientes"**
-columnas
 - "id
 - "nombre"
 - "apellidop"
 - "apellidom"
 - "direccion"
 - "telefono"

***Este es el codigo completo.***

```
<?php /*session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
}*/

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {     
    $nombre = filter_var(($_POST['nombre']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $apellidop = filter_var(($_POST['apellidop']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $apellidom = filter_var(($_POST['apellidom']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $direccion = filter_var(($_POST['direccion']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $telefono = filter_var(($_POST['telefono']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);



    $errores ='';

    if (empty($nombre) or empty($apellidop)  or empty($apellidom)  or empty($direccion)  or empty($telefono) ) 
    {
        $errores .= '<li>Por favor rellena todos los datos correctamente</li>';
    } 

    else    
    {
            try 
            {
            $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=drfreddy', 'root', '');
            } 
            catch (PDOException $e) 
                {
                echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
                }
           //Aqui creo esta mi error...
            $statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT nombre, apellidop, apellidop * FROM pacientes WHERE nombre = :nombre, apellidop = :apellidop, apellidom = :apellidom');

            $statement->execute(array(':nombre'  => $nombre, ':apellidop' => $apellidop, ':apellidom' => $apellidom));

            $resultado = $statement->fetch();

            if ($resultado != false) 
            {
            $errores .= '<li>El paciente ya existe en la base de datos</li>';
            }


    }  //Termina IF

    if ($errores == '') {
        $statement = $conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO pacientes (id, nombre, apellidop, apellidom, direccion, telefono) VALUES (null, :nombre, :apellidop, :apellidom, :direccion, :telefono)');

        $statement->execute(array(
            ':nombre' => $nombre,
            ':apellidop' => $apellidop,
            ':apellidom' => $apellidom,
            ':direccion' => $direccion,
            ':telefono' => $telefono
        ));


        header('Location: pacientes.php');
    }

}
require 'views/pacientes.view.php';

?>
```

Comment: **Tendrás que utilizar otro identificador de usuario**, como por ejemplo un número de socio o dni como clave primaria. Si solo compruebas nombre y apellido, ¿Que haces cuando tengas dos usuarios que se llamen igual?

Comment: Yo creo que tienes que controlarlo por un ID que sea indistingible , como  ocmenta @ViejoCadillac , el DNI , id de socio y fuera.

Comment: Alguna clave única (que sea dato de paciente) tienes que usar. Algo como el DNI o el teléfono) Lo mejor creo que seria por DNI. Una vez tengas tu clave única, simplemente es hacer una query para comprobar si existe o no antes de registrarlo.

Comment: Hola, tu error esta justamente donde tú lo marcas, el código SQL para verificar si existe esa información tiene un error de sintaxis, debes eliminar el * de la siguiente forma `SELECT nombre, apellidop, apellidop FROM pacientes WHERE nombre = :nombre, apellidop = :apellidop, apellidom = :apellidom` por ese error siempre te retorna false, no porque no exista sino porque hay error de sintaxis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes editar la tabla MySQL y añadir un Index que contenga conjuntamente el campo nombre y apellidos. Ese index lo identificas como valor único, de mamera que tu tabla no aceptará dos registros con esos campos iguales.

En la petición SQL haces un INSERT IGNORE, con lo que al insertar un registro repetido, no lo insertará e ignorará el error.

Puedes comprobar si el usuario se ha insertado o si era un usuario repetido recuperando el mysqli_insert_id despues de hacer el insert. En el caso de estar repetido ese valor vendrá vacío.

Comment: Muy factible tu propuesta, podrías apoyarme, con un ejemplo de código. Gracias.

Comment: Finalmente hice lo de poner el nombre completo en la Base de Datos, creo que es la solución al problema desde otra perspectiva, te califico como la respuesta aceptada, sin embargo me queda la duda de como comparar mas de dos valores introducidos en un formulario y que se cotejen contra la base de datos de que estos no esten repetidos. En fin gracias por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

**Intenta con esto:**

```
if ($resultado != false){
    $errores .= '<li>El paciente ya existe en la base de datos</li>';
} else {
    $statement = $conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO pacientes (id, nombre, apellidop, apellidom, direccion, telefono) VALUES (null, :nombre, :apellidop, :apellidom, :direccion, :telefono)');

    $statement->execute(array(
        ':nombre' => $nombre,
        ':apellidop' => $apellidop,
        ':apellidom' => $apellidom,
        ':direccion' => $direccion,
        ':telefono' => $telefono
    ));


    header('Location: pacientes.php');
    /* Asegurándonos de que el código interior no será ejecutado cuando se realiza la redirección. */
    exit;
}
```

**Nota:**
Recuerde que header() debe ser llamado antes de mostrar nada por pantalla, etiquetas HTML, líneas en blanco desde un fichero o desde PHP.
**Nota:**
Recuerda usar exit despues del header.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias cosas que hay que tener en cuenta:

1. necesitas algún tipo de indice único, usar el nombre + apellido como puede tener problemas si tienes homónimos (pasará seguro), yo te recomendaría agregar una campo único, puede ser el numero identificador de tu país o hasta el email (aunque puede que alguien no tenga, caso que es raro).
2. Agregar una constrain de unique en la nueva columna.
3. Manejar los errores al intentar crear un usuario repetido, tienes dos opciones, manejar el error que da la base de datos (por el unique) o hacer una consulta antes para revisar que ese usuario no exista.

**Consejo:** 
Evalúa la posibilidad de usar un ORM que te haga todo esto por ti.